# Moments of a parametric probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have the following probability density function :

$\ p(x)=p_{a,\lambda}(x)=\frac{a\lambda^a}{(x+\lambda)^{1+a}},$
$ \lambda>0, a>0$ and I need to:

1) Give the values $\beta$ ,$\beta>0$ for which $\mathbb{E}(X^\beta)$ is finite

2) Show that  $\mathbb{E}(X^\beta)$ can be written as $\lambda^bc$, where $b$ and $c$ are expressions of $a$ and $\beta$.

To solve question 2 I calculated $\int_{0}^{+\infty} x^{\beta}\frac{a\lambda^a}{(x+\lambda)^{1+a}}dx$ by parts and found $a\lambda^a[\frac{x^\beta}{-a(x+\lambda)^a}]^{+\infty}_{0}+\beta\lambda^a \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{\beta-1}}{(x+\lambda)^a}dx$, could someone give me a hint on how to proceed from here?
And for question 1 I don't really have any clue.
Thanks a lot

Comment: You should mention the non-negative support of the distribution. [This distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) is closely linked to the Pareto and Beta-prime distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the integral as a Beta function with $x=\lambda\tan^2t,\,y=\sin^2t$. The boundary term is $0$ provided $\beta<\alpha$; you can see this from the $x\to\infty$ behaviour of $\frac{x^\beta}{(x+\lambda)^\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's much clearer now